# Applying convolutional neural network over text documents using 1-D tf-idf feature vectors

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, text-mining, convolutional-neural-network

I want to apply a CNN over documents. I have tf-idf vectors of documents with me (one vector per document).

My question is, is 1D CNN applicable in this case? The reason I am asking this question is that I have read 1D convolutions being applied to sequence of vectors and I have sequence of scalars (tf-idf vector) as input in this case, so is it applicable?

Comment: 1D or 2D convolutions over sequence of vectors or a matrix? I heard of 2D convolution over a matrix and ecah matrix represents a document.

Comment: I have input as document which is presented as tf-idf vector to the model. Generally a document is passed as seqeuence of vector to CNN, with each vector corresponding to vector embedding of the corresponding word in the document. But in my case I have only tf-idf vector of the document and not the document itself, so I cannot pass word embeddings.

Answer (score 1):

In TFIDF representation "neighborhood" is not interpretable. The 1st number in a document vector has just as much relation to the 2nd and to the 100th.
While in case of a standard time series or sequence analysis "neighborhood" is interpretable.
On the other hand, if you could re-order the TFIDF representation in a way, that makes sense from the analysis perspective (eg: ordering based on the "sentiment" of the word), maybe 1D CNN would show some good results.

Comment: That's exactly was my thought, but I have seen some papers applying CNN to tf-idf representation. That made me think if CNN over tf-idf makes sense or not? (Ref: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P16/P16-1036.pdf)

Comment: As far as I understand in the referenced paper they use sequence of words - more precisely the sequence of n-gram letters (word hashing) - as the input to the convolutional layer.